# To store data in mySQL using editText android

Tags: mysql, android-edittext

I have a concepts of storing a data in mySQL using editText(ie, UserName and Password), But i'm not having any idea how to proceed, Could anyone send me a link for above.. Thanks in advance

Comment: http://www.vogella.com/articles/AndroidSQLite/article.html

Comment: Hi friends, I can't understand why you are guys making my query on hold, whether there is any mistake which I made in my query if means please correct me. Thanks in advance..

Answer (score 1):

first of all, Android doesnt support mySql, it supports SQLite. Read about SQLiteOpenHelper to get some overview on this.
If you want to use an outter database which works on mySql, you need to create some sort of php API that will handle your requests

Answer (score 0):

Without using the web server you can't even think about Database server.

[image: Procedure to connect]